# read access to iam role in eks cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, rbac

I am trying to grant a readonly iam role the readonly access to the cluster. For this I have created a service account, clusterrole and a clusterrolebinding.
However, while accessing the kubectl get pods using readonly iam role it gives me below error:

**pods is forbidden: User "readonly" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"**

Can some pls help me to resolve this error.

cluster role :

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: readrole
  namespace: kube-system
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
```

service account :

```
kubectl create sa readonly -n kube-system
```

created cluster role binding

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: readrole-binding
  namespace: kube-system
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: readonly
  namespace: kube-system    
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: readrole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Also, let me know if there is another approach too using the default roles provided by kubernetes.

Comment: Did you add this user to aws-auth configmap?

Comment: @OguzhanAygun Yes we have added

Comment: For reference:                                                                                                                             mapRoles:
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::**********:role/eks-worker-role
  username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
  groups:
    - system:bootstrappers
    - system:nodes
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam:*******:role/cluster-admin
  username: admin
  groups:
  - system:masters
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::*************:role/ReadOnly
  username: readonly

Comment: @OguzhanAygun  can you please guide

Comment: can you change first part to rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods

Comment: @OguzhanAygun Its still giving the same error.